# Steps to solve equitation

Tags: algorithms, systems-of-equations

While I'm checking the solution of the problem mentioned below, I could not figure out the steps to go from each step. I would like to know what are the detailed steps to go from each step of the solution ? and also where can I find a book or a source to learn think kind of equation resolving

> Suppose we are comparing implementations of insertion sort and merge
>   sort on the same machine. For inputs of size n , insertion sort runs
>   in 8n² steps, while merge sort runs in 64n lgn steps. For which values
>   of n does insertion sort beat merge sort?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you divide both sides by $8n$ giving $$n \lt 8 \lg n$$
Then you raise $2$ to the power of each side
$$2^n \lt 2^{8 \lg n}=(2^{\lg n})^8=n^8$$
The last step is just by evaluation.  We know $2^n$ will eventually get larger than any given power of $n$.  We just need to compute where it happens.  Here it is $43$

Comment: Thank you it make more sense now but can you please explain more the second step why it's valid to raise 2 to the power of each side ? and why the number 2 ? and why 2^8lgn = (2^lgn)^8 = n^8 ? any book or course online to learn this ? thank you @Ross

Comment: It is valid because $2^x$ is monotonically increasing, so if $x \lt y, 2^x \lt 2^y$.  We choose $2$ because of the definition of $\lg n$ that $2^{\lg n}=n$.  The rest is from the normal [properties of exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties) and should be covered in any algebra text.